# Nuxt Sitemap not updating in SSR mode

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js

My project is in SSR mode with a cache time of 15 minutes. The sitemap.xml file works fine for what exists at build time, but it doesn't update after 15 minutes. Is there anything else I need to do to enable this functionality?

We're using pm2 to start the app. This is a Nuxt 2 app.

I setup the new sitemap function to fetch URLs from our headless CMS.

I set cacheTime to 15 minutes.

I checked the sitemap.xml, and it looked correct.

I updated our CMS to publish another article.

I waited 15 minutes.

The new article was not present, even though I expected it to be.

```js
const path = require('path');
const fs = require('fs');
const env = process.env.NODE_ENV;
const envPath = path.resolve(process.cwd(), `.env.${env}`);
const defaultEnvPath = path.resolve(process.cwd(), '.env');
const axios = require('axios');

require('dotenv').config({
    path: fs.existsSync(envPath) ? envPath : defaultEnvPath,
});

export default {
debug: true,
ssr: true,
port: process.env.PORT || 3000,
target: 'server',
// ...
async sitemap() {
        const articleRoutes = [];
        const now = new Date();
        await axios
            .get(ARTICLE_URL)
            .then((response) => {
                response.data.data.forEach((route) => {
                    const publishDate = new Date(route.publish_date);
                    if (publishDate < now) articleRoutes.push(`/${route.id}`);
                    });
                })
                .catch((error) => {
                    throw new Error(error);
                });
            return {
                cacheTime: 1000 * 60 * 15, // 15 minutes
                hostname: 'www.foo.bar',
                gzip: true,
                exclude: [...],
                routes: articleRoutes,
            };
        },
```

Comment: If you want it to update, you can try to make a call with that: https://nuxtjs.org/docs/directory-structure/store#the-nuxtserverinit-action If you write it there where you're doing, it will only happen once during the build of your app. But all of this should not matter since you're using a headless CMS and that it probably has a webhook that will trigger a rebuild automatically for you.

Comment: Mainly, understand that what you're doing inside of the `nuxt.config.js` file in your code snippet, is made once at build time (`yarn build`) and never run again. A webhook is meant for that purpose tho and integrates well with Netlify + any other headless CMS combo.

Answer (score 0):

I went and did a more thorough look through the documentation after reading some of the comments and saw I had made a mistake. I moved my api call onto the routes property, like in the following link, and my code started working:

https://sitemap.nuxtjs.org/usage/sitemap-options#from-a-function-which-returns-a-promise

```js
sitemap() {
        return {
            cacheTime: 1000 * 60 * 15, // 15 minutes
            hostname: 'www.foo.bar',
            gzip: true,
            exclude: [
                //...
            ],
            routes: async () => {
                const articleRoutes = [];
                const now = new Date();
                await axios
                    .get(ARTICLES_URL)
                    .then((response) => {
                        response.data.data.forEach((route) => {
                            const publishDate = new Date(route.publish_date);
                            if (publishDate < now) articleRoutes.push(`/${route.id}`);
                        });
                    })
                    .catch((error) => {
                        throw new Error(error);
                    });
          return articleRoutes;
            },
        };
```

It now seems to work and automatically rebuilds the sitemap as the documentation suggests.